# OData V2 SetProperty in onInit

Tags: odata, sapui5

I need to set the property to DataSet during onInit, to change the visiblity of some controls in my View. I could solve this problem with setting the visibility dynamically in controller. But I want to use the expression binding and the visible property in the View to set visibilites.

I'm getting an error in the function OnStartSetVisibilites. self.getView().getBindingContext() returns UNDEFINED. Without the sPath, I can't use setProperty. And without setProperty, my View-Controls don't know the visible-value.

How to fix this?

View:

```
<uxap:ObjectPageSubSection visible="{= ${Responsible} === '1'}" id="leader">
                    
</uxap:ObjectPageSubSection>
```

OnInit in View-Controller:

```
    onInit: function () {
        var startupParameters = this.getOwnerComponent().getComponentData().startupParameters;

        var sWorkitem = startupParameters.TASK[0];

        this.setModel(this.getOwnerComponent().getModel());
        this.getModel().metadataLoaded().then(function () {
            var sObjectPath = this.getModel().createKey("DataSet", {  
                Workitem: sWorkitem 
            });
            this.getView().bindElement({
                path: "/" + sObjectPath
            });
        }.bind(this));

        var self = this;
        var model = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();

        this.getModel().read("/CharSet", {
            success: function (response) {
                $.sap.Chars = response.results;

                self.onStartSetVisibilities(model, self);

            }
        });

        // self.getView().attachAfterRendering(function () {
        //  self.onStartSetVisibilities(model, self);
        // });
        
    }
```

OnStartSetVisibilities:

```
    onStartSetVisibilities: function (model, self) {
        var char = model.getProperty(„GeneralData/Char");

        if (char !== "" || char !== null) {
          model.setProperty(self.getView().getBindingContext().sPath + "/Responsible", 
          this.getResponsibleForChar(char));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together some code which might solve your issue (it's untested so it may contain syntax errors!).

I introduced the concept of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which simplifies the asynchronous behavior of JS. I also replaced some of the inner functions with [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so you don't have to deal with `that` or `self`. Arrow functions basically use the `this` of the scope they are defined within.

Your app should now have a proper flow.

1. First you bind the view.
2. After the view is bound  you read the `CharSet`.
3. After the data is read you set the visibility stuff

```js
onInit: function () {
    const startupParameters = this.getOwnerComponent().getComponentData().startupParameters;
    const sWorkitem = startupParameters.TASK[0];
    
    this._bindView(sWorkitem)
        .then(() => this._readCharSet())
        .then(() => this._setVisibilities())
},
    
_bindView: function (sWorkitem) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
        oModel.metadataLoaded().then(() => {
            const sPath = "/" + oModel.createKey("DataSet", {  
                Workitem: sWorkitem 
            });
            this.getView().bindElement({
                path: sPath,
                events: {
                    change: resolve,
                    dataReceived: resolve
                }
            });
        });
    });
},
    
_readCharSet: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
        oModel.read("/CharSet", {
            success: resolve
        });
    });
},
    
_setVisibilities: function () {
    const oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
    const sChar = oModel.getProperty("GeneralData/Char");

    if (sChar) {
        // ...
    }
}
```